# How to get the branch name created recently

Tags: git, git-branch

I am using `Bit-Bucket` and I've almost `50 branches` has been created so far and I am not sure how to fetch the following details either using command line or in Bit-Bucket UI tool?

1. Name of the last branch created?
2. History with Dates when the branches has been created?

Is this possible to get this info?

Comment: From a strict git perspective, no, branches have no metadata on their own, *commits* do. The question will boil down to how to do this in BitBucket UI.

Comment: Is there a reason to keep branches around? Some folks do, but deleting them when they're unneeded is a common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With command line, you can do `git branch -a` and it will give you list of all your branches on local as well as remote.

You can use `--sort` option in `git branch` command to sort the branches based on creator date:

`git branch -a --sort=-creatordate`

`-` will sort descending, without -, it will sort ascending. So, if you sort it ascending, you will get the last branch created at the first position.

Do check `git for-each-ref --help`, it provides a lot of options that will help in these type of situations.

This should answer both of your questions:

**Below command gives Branch list + Author + Created Date:**

```
 git branch -a --format="%(refname) | Authored by: %(authorname) | Created Date: %(authordate)"
```

Comment: Yes, I know when that branch was created and how to get name of the last branch ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Updated answer again for History with Dates when the branches were created.

Comment: Perfect. I really like this +1. If we can format authordate to dd/MM/yyyy that will certainly help

Comment: There's predefined format in git for short date [in YYYY-MM-DD]. You can append `:short` to give the short date like below:

`git branch -a --format="%(refname) | Authored by: %(authorname) | Created Date: %(authordate:short)"`

Comment: Thanks. I used `git branch -a --format="%(refname) | Authored by: %(authorname) | Created Date: %(authordate:format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"`